# Informix, Procedure, Converting String to Time

Tags: date, stored-procedures, time, informix

I want to call the informix sp below from c# but am having trouble getting it to compile.  I want to pass it a string like '2012-11-22' and two times like '08:15:00' and convert them to a date and two datetimes but I can't seem to find the correct informix function.  I've spent the whole day trying to figure this out, any help is apprecitated.

Not sure if the code below will compile as I had to remove some sensitive parts but I'm hoping it's enough to give you the idea.

the TO_DATE functions are incorrect i think

```
create procedure up_myproc(
calndr_dt CHAR(15)
, actvty_typ CHAR(5)
, actvty_start_tm CHAR(15)
, actvty_end_tm CHAR(15)
, actvty_cap SMALLINT
)

DEFINE calendar_activity_id int;
DEFINE activity_details_id int;

-- calendar activity
insert into caa61140 (
caa61140001
, caa61140004
, caa61140005
)
values (
0
, org_id
, DATE(calndr_dt)
);

LET calendar_activity_id = DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd1');

-- activity details
insert into caa61240 (
caa61240001
, caa61240002
, caa61240003
, caa61240004
)
values (
0
,calendar_activity_id
, TO_DATE(actvty_start_tm, "%H:%M" )
, TO_DATE (actvty_end_tm, "%H:%M" )
);

LET activity_details_id = DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd1');

-- calendar matter
insert into caa61340(caa61340001
, caa61340002)
SELECT activity_details_id
, caa60840003 matter_typ
  FROM caa60840 -- valid matter types;
  WHERE caa60840001=org_id
  AND caa60840002=actvty_typ;

end procedure;
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd approach this is to use the implicit conversion abilities of Informix:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE up_myproc(
    calndr_dt       DATETIME YEAR TO DAY,
    actvty_typ      CHAR(5),
    actvty_start_tm INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND,
    actvty_end_tm   INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND,  
    actvty_cap      SMALLINT)

    DEFINE tm_1 DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND;
    DEFINE tm_2 DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND;

    LET tm_1 = EXTEND(clndr_dt, YEAR TO SECOND) + actvty_start_tm;
    LET tm_2 = EXTEND(clndr_dt, YEAR TO SECOND) + actvty_end_tm;

    ...
```

The key decision here was to treat the time as an INTERVAL HOUR TO MINUTE rather than as a DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE.  If you had a formal DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE parameter, you'd need to convert to an INTERVAL so that you could do arithmetic.  You can add a DATETIME and an INTERVAL; the result is a DATETIME.  You can subtract two DATETIME values; the result is an INTERVAL.  You can add or subtract two INTERVAL values and the the result is an INTERVAL.  But that's about it.  So, to get to an INTERVAL from DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND, you'd subtract DATETIME(00:00:00) HOUR TO SECOND.

You'd call this revised function with character string arguments, just as you do at the moment.

If you can't stomach changing the interface like that, then:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE up_myproc(
    calndr_dt_str       DATETIME YEAR TO DAY,
    actvty_typ          CHAR(5),
    actvty_start_tm_str CHAR(15),
    actvty_end_tm_str   CHAR(15),  
    actvty_cap          SMALLINT)

    DEFINE calndr_dt       DATETIME YEAR TO DAY;
    DEFINE actvty_start_tm INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND;
    DEFINE actvty_end_tm   INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND;  

    DEFINE tm_1 DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND;
    DEFINE tm_2 DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND;

    LET actvty_dt       = actvty_dt_str
    LET actvty_start_tm = actvty_start_tm_str;
    LET actvty_end_tm   = actvty_end_tm_str;
    LET tm_1            = EXTEND(clndr_dt, YEAR TO SECOND) + actvty_start_tm;
    LET tm_2            = EXTEND(clndr_dt, YEAR TO SECOND) + actvty_end_tm;

    ...
```

This still relies on the conversions, but hides them in the procedure body and makes them explicit.

*Code untested; there might be something I've overlooked.*